# Find questions that are marked as duplicate

Tags: support

I falsely marked a few questions as duplicate until I recognized the mistake (misread the date). 
Is there a way to find questions I marked as duplicate recently or just generally search for questions that are marked as duplicate,
so that I can undo the change?

Comment: You can narrow it down a bit.  Go to your profile > Activity > Votes > Closure.  Look for the ones that have [duplicate] in the title.  Keep in mind that the date does not matter, selecting a newer Q+A as the canonical is fine.

Comment: @HansPassant that did it. Thanks a lot.